# How to call a function for each String in an array using ASM

Tags: java, bytecode

So i'm trying to build an Array of strings using ASM, however i want to call a function for each string in the array. I can't figure out how to do this, been searching all over the internet for a while now. This is what i got so far for building the array:

```
InstructionAdapter builder = new InstructionAdapter(mv);
builder.iconst(strings.length);
builder.newarray(Type.getType(String.class));
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    builder.dup();
    builder.iconst(i);
    builder.aconst(strings[i]);
    builder.astore(InstructionAdapter.OBJECT_TYPE);
}
builder.putstatic(callOwner.name, FIELD_NAME, "[Ljava/lang/String;");
```

As you can see i have an array of strings, called `strings` which i iterate and build the array.

This generates an array which might look like this

```
private String[] somearray = { "Test" };
```

Now what i want to do is call a function on each string in the array, say i have a function called decode i would call it like this `decode("Test")`. So i want the array to look like this

```
private String[] somearray = { decode("Test") };
```

How do i make it call decode on each element in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just insert the opcode whenever you load the value to be stored in the array. Using the code you posted in the question, it should look something like this, assuming that decode is a static method defined in `MyClass`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    builder.dup();
    builder.iconst(i);
    builder.aconst(strings[i]);
    builder.invokestatic("LMyClass;", "decode", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;", false);
    builder.astore(InstructionAdapter.OBJECT_TYPE);
}
```

Of course, that's only if you want the decode() calls to happen at runtime. Since you're only dealing with constant strings here, you may want to consider just doing the decode calls at translation time and only writing the results to the transformed classfile. In that case, you code would look something along the lines of this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    builder.dup();
    builder.iconst(i);
    builder.aconst(decode(strings[i]));
    builder.astore(InstructionAdapter.OBJECT_TYPE);
}
```